# Soft keyboard ... not related to EditText?

Tags: android, keyboard

If hard keyboard is available, it generates key events processed by onKey onKeyDown, onKeyUp, etc.

If hard keyboard is unavailable, it appears natural to show soft keyboard in expectation it will generate same key events.

Is it possible to show a keyboard other than via EditText?

The only idea I can come up with is referring to EditText code :) Someone may already have done that.

*A proposito*, Android Terminal Emulator does exactly that: it allows entering keys from soft keyboard without using EditText, therefore the idea is not pointless.

Comment: Try android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" in your root activity in your manifest file.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew. It makes soft keyboard visible at activity start. But I want to hide and show keyboard within activity.

Comment: So say onClick perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my research and from [this](http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/93/android-show-hide-soft-keyboard-programmatically/) article, it seems you can show/hide the soft keyboard rather easily but it's not recommended.

From that website, the code is as follows.

Showing the keyboard...perhaps onClick or onOptionsItemSelected:

```
EditText txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
// only will trigger it if no physical keyboard is open
inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(txtName, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Hiding the keyboard:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Now again, this method is not recommended in the guidelines but if you would like to try it, this would be the way to go.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Andrew. Just I want to extend the article, you refer to.

You probably noticed, that the article (and the code above) uses *EditText*, which is not quite I was after. Fortunately, as I've found out, this works with any *TextView* as long as it is **focused**.

How to make a view focused without a hard keyboard? Make it focusableInTouchMode and requestFocus.

Here is what I have for layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"   >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:imeOptions="actionGo"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text="==== Just to make it visible ======"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
        <requestFocus/>
    </TextView>


</FrameLayout>
```

Note, that you can use android:imeOptions and android:inputType to set up the type and appearance of the soft keyboard.

And the code looks pretty straightforward. you bring up the keyboard on click and dismiss it when Action key (code KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) is pressed. Also BACK button has to be processed by the system, otherwise
we will get stuck forever :)

The code below assumes API 3+.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE)
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.startup);

    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text); 

    final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imm.showSoftInput(v, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        `}
    });

    tv.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                case KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Log.d("KbdTest", "Action Down. Key Code: " + keyCode);
                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
                            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
                    return (keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);

                case KeyEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Log.d("KbdTest", "Action Up. Key Code: " + keyCode);
                    return (keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);

                default:
                    Log.d("KbdTest", "Unknown action (" + action + "). Key Code: " + keyCode);
                    return false;
            }

        }
    }); 
 }
```

Honestly, I am not quite impressed. Firstly it shows the cursor, while I don't want to see it. Secondly, it sometimes manages to edit the text (!), even though *return true*  from *onKey* is expected to suppress any interference.

Anyway, this is a great starting point! :)